# @@deriving sexp is not working on utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

I'm running this code in utop:

```
# type u = { a: int; b: float } [@@deriving sexp];;
```

But the expected declarations of s-expression converters are not generated.

I have Core 0.11.0 and utop version 2.1.0 installed.

the version of Ocaml is 4.06.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `-require` so that the ppx is loaded. In addition (that's specific to this driver), you need to pass its runtime in scope using `-require sexplib` and a manual `open Sexplib.Std`:

```
% utop -require ppx_sexp_conv -require sexplib                  
utop # open Sexplib.Std;;
utop # type u = { a: int; b: float } [@@deriving sexp];;
type u = { a : int; b : float; }
val u_of_sexp : Sexplib0.Sexp.t -> u = <fun>
val sexp_of_u : u -> Sexplib0.Sexp.t = <fun>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked, the only thing is that It requires to install the package ppx_deriving as explained here: https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_sexp_conv/issues/21

Comment: Also, it worked only with `utop -require ppx_sexp_conv` and instead of `open Sexplib.Std`, I can `open Core` or `open Base`.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the extra info. There are several ways to use this deriver indeed.